# What provides missing command package install hints?

Tags: command-line, package-management

On some Ubuntu systems I get hints like:

```
$ nc

Command 'nc' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install netcat-openbsd      # version 1.206-1ubuntu1, or
apt install ncat                # version 7.80+dfsg1-2build1
apt install netcat-traditional  # version 1.10-41.1ubuntu1
```

What is generating these hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These come from the [`command-not-found` utility](https://launchpad.net/command-not-found) which itself is in the package `command-not-found`.

```
$ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- nc
```

If you install that package, you need to run an extra `apt update` to download the database that `command-not-found` uses (e.g., from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/cnf/).

[This answer at the UNIX & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501249) explains how this ends up getting integrated with the shell.